# Where does the number in AKS resources comes from?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I need to do some operation on internal resources inside AKS ResourceGroup over API. I need to know how is the "23093...." number defined. How can I find it? I need to find aks-vnet-23093... resource by it's name via terraform data structure so I need to know how to generate this number.

[image: scr1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the number is created randomly by Azure, of curse, the Vnet type is Basic. If you want to create a Vnet with a specific name using Terraform. You can use an advance Vnet. For more details, you can read the document [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html).

If you use the type Basic Vnet. When you create the AKS cluster, there will be output and you can find like this:
[image]

Then you can use the command `az resource list --resource-group nodeResourceGroup -o table` and you will find like this:
[image]

The Vnet name will be the same as it except the number after and the number is created randomly. So you cannot know the number before creating it by Azure.

Comment: Too bad it's randomly generated. That would make so much more sense to generate it's name in consistent way like AKS managed resource group name is generated. It's easy to get to this resource group then.

Comment: To get name over az-cli it's even better to use: `az network vnet list -g MC_managed_RG_name --query '[].name'`. You get name directly.

Comment: Also advanced networking on terraform isn't working so far. [Here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1434) is description. It will be released with version 0.12.

Comment: @Mateusz Thanks for your sharing. Do you mean advanced network cannot be defined with a specific name using terraform?

Comment: @Mateusz I test the advanced network. Actually, there are two networks in kubernets. one is a private network for the pods which we just can define the range. The other one is what we talk about and we can create it with a specific name, but it's not in the node resource group MC_xxxx_xxxx_location, the network is in the resource group where the Kubernets cluster in.

Comment: sorry for late notice but I was investigating this. It occurred that its indeed possible to create this. Problem in my case was that there wasn't `network_profile { network_plugin = "azure" }` part in my `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource. I tested it and it works correctly. Thanks for advices!